# Need to find a way to edit a password protected .bak file of SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've some `.bak` files created from different PC's but I need to restore and be able to edit
them. When I'm trying to restore it says that file is password protected.

So how could I change the table values? I also need to export these values directly from Excel or Access files.

I would be so much glad if someone could help! These `.bak` files are of SQL Server 2005.

Could I do this with win 7 ultimate 64bit, with any higher version like SQL Server 2008 or 2012 installed?

I mean can I make changes with different version of SQL Server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to ask the person who created those `.bak` files what password he/she used.

Comment: Need to find a way to edit a password protected .bak file of SQL Server 2005 sounds like `Help me to hack`

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm in a similar situation trying to extract data for a client who forgot their password.